# Why Android phone cannot have second display?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, external-display

There are many questions about mirroring the screen, but I am interested in why no Android phone cannot have a second display (not interested in casting the screen, nor folded displays), etc through USB-C or maybe later through HDMI to big 777" displays. There should be no technical limitations.

Comment: "There should be no technical limitations."  Ok, should and is are 2 different things.  Are you sure there aren't any limitations?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Can you estimate when it is technically possible to have second display?